# Datatable sorting on multiple column not working well

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm facing a little difficulty with the sorting behavior of Datatable. The sorting works, but it's only shorting by the column "ID". When I try to sort by any column, it will sort based on the ID column that contains auto-incremented values.
Here is the Jscode code:

```
var datatables = $('#plans_data').DataTable({
    "Processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "order":[],
    "ajax":{
        url:"../controller/fetch.php",
        type:"POST"
    },
     "lengths":[10,50,50,100],
    "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":[0,8],
            "orderable":false,

        },

    ],


});
```

I have a php file where all the query are stored. Here is a part of the php file code:

````
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM plans ";
if(isset($_POST["order"]))
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY ID ASC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $row["ID"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["num_clas"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["num_tf"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["num_maj"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["nom_p"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["nom_Geom"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["categorie"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["superficie"];
    $sub_array[] = $row["arrondis"];
    $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"              =>  intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"      =>  $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"   =>  get_total_all_records(),
    "data"              =>  $data
);
echo json_encode($output);


?>```
When I click on the sorting icon, it sorts but only on the "ID" column. I dont really understand why and I've tried to fine some issues but all went wrong.
````

Comment: If it sorts only on the ID field, your code is probably not recognizing your `$_POST` and executing this line: `$query .= 'ORDER BY ID ASC ';`.
Try to do an `echo $query;` to see exactly what query is being formed and run.

Comment: I've tried to get the content of the $query with echo $query;. This is the result `SELECT * FROM plans WHERE num_clas LIKE "%%" OR num_tf LIKE "%%" OR num_maj LIKE "%%" OR nom_p LIKE "%%" OR nom_Geom LIKE "%%" OR arrondis LIKE "%%" **ORDER BY 3 asc** ` So it seems it only takes the index of the column to sort.

Comment: I don't know where you could be getting this from. Where are all the `like` conditions coming from? I don't see that on your code. Also, your ORDER BY is probably getting the wrong `$_POST` variable. Doing a `sort by 3` is probably not what you intended. Also, it doesn't make sense to do a `like '%%'` as it doesn't exclude anything.

Comment: I finally solved my problem by comparing the index  and replacing it by the real column name and it works well

Comment: your code allows SQL injection attack. Add your parameters into prepare call so library would take care about it.